# Javascript Array init with values vs init and push

Tags: javascript, arrays, initialization

If I have 3 `const`'s: `value1`, `value2`, and `value3`

Is there any difference between:

```
let myArray = [];
myArray.push(value1, value2, value3);
```

and

```
let myArray = [value1, value2, value3];
```

I'm tidying up a script and don't understand why it was written using the first form.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Use Git blame and ask the other developer.

Comment: `Array.prototype.push` could be overwritten, e.g. it could be decorated with a logger. In that case the first snippet could call a function that the second snippet won't.

Comment: Thanks @jabaa :) - More curious if any benefit to either method - the 2nd form seems cleaner to me, but I've seen a lot of other posts where people are init and then push in a single line which makes me wonder why they're even doing that in the first place when they can use the 2nd form.

Comment: You should ask these people. There could be reasons for  in code you didn't see. In JavaScript you can manipulate the built-in behavior and even some libraries do this. It's bad practice but it exists. Without more context there is no reason for the second snippet.

Comment: @jabaa - push isn't being overwritten. There's not much more to the code apart from the array being used. Why do you say there's no reason for the second form?

Comment: I meant, there is no reason for the first form. The first snippet shouldn't pass the code review.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is in the first situation, the array is initialized as empty without any items, and then the items are pushed inside it.

But in the second situation, the array is initialized with 3 items inside it.

Comment: Thanks - I gathered that much - More curious if there's any benefit to using one method over the other.

Comment: Sure, the first method you can make some operations between you initialize the array as empty, and add items to it.